# Are the structures of "with one player less" and "with one less player" the same?

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order

> This year we were very unlucky because we played **with one player less against** Barcelona.

Does "with one player less" have the same stractures as sentences below?

> 1. This year we were very unlucky because we played **with one less player** against Barcelona.
> 2. I don't like sleep **with windows open**.
> 3. They have returned **with one soldier missing.**

Comment: 1. has the same meaning, and a related structure. 2 and 3 have very different structures. You can say _The windows were open_ and _One soldier was missing_, but you can't say _One player was less_. _Less_ is part of the quantifier, not directly a modifier of _player_.

Comment: I couldn’t understand what kind of structure is “one less man” if it is adverb why we use “with”?

Comment: _One less_ or _one ... less_ behaves like any other quantifier, such as a number. _We played with ten players_; _We played with too many players_; _We played with one player_; _We played with half a player_; _We played with one player less_. All are parallel. But note that _less_ semantically requires a standard of comparison, which is implied here. It might be "less than last time" or "less than we expected", or "less than the number that _they_ played with".

Comment: We can say _We played with one player injured_, and that is like your 2 and 3: it implies that one (particular) player was injured. But _one player less_ doesn't imply that "one player was less": that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: [correction: I don't like **to sleep** with open windows.]

Comment: Thank you so much. We cam say we played with  ten players but can’t say with players that are ten.

Answer (score 0):

Right, OK, this is an interesting question. The structures are not the same. I address some of the issues raised here. Not all of them.

- This year we were very unlucky because we played with one less player against Barcelona.

**I** would say this like this: because we played the game **minus one/a player**.

Less would have to be: fewer players. A fewer number of players. A lower number of players. But: less coffee, less butter for an uncountable noun.

Though, one could argue: we played the game with one player more and one player less. Where one is a number.

- I don't like to sleep with open windows. versus closed windows. open and closed are simple adjectives here.
- They have returned with one soldier missing [from the squad or battalion or whatever.

Here, missing implies a longer adverbial phrase: missing [from the group].

- We did the work with one employee sleeping [on the job].

Also, be aware that "one soldier missing" is not one missing soldier here.

They returned with a missing soldier. would mean that a soldier who was missing returned with them.